# String Reversal LC3 Assembly Language

Tags: string, loops, assembly, reverse, lc3

I'm in the process of writing a .asm program based on LC-3 Assembly Language which will loop through a list of strings, reverse each one, and store it back into it's place in the list.

For Example:

```
     STRINGS .STRINGZ "aabbb"
                      "bbcva"
                      "abcde"
```

The program would flip that list to "`bbbaa`", "`avcbb`", and "`edcba`" - thus, reversing the strings but maintaining the list ordering.

I'm currently working on a nested-loop idea, where the outer loop will go from string to string and the inner loop will flip them and it's kicking my butt! I wrote the code in Java to do the same and it took me 5 minutes, but for some reason, assembly is just pooping on my brain. Any pointers on how to go about doing this?

Here's what I have thus far, in  a mix of psuedo and assembly:

```
    .ORIG x3000
    LEA R0, STRINGS            ; Load the address of the first char of the list of strings
    Loop until NOP is found, signaling end of the string.
    LEA R1, the address above  ; stores the address of the last char
    LDR R2, #0 Offset +1       ; load the first char to be flipped
    LDR R3, #0 Offset +2       ; load the last char to be flipped
    STR R3, #0 Offset +1       ; store the last char in the mem addr of the first
    STR R2, #0 Offset +2       ; store the first char in the addr of the last
    ADD R1, R1 + 1             ; increment the addr of the first char to move to the second
    ADD R2, R2 - 1             ; decrement the addr of the last char the move the second-to-last
    loop back to beginning somehow
```

And I've not the slightest idea how to do the outer loop between strings.

TL;DR - Assembly Program to reverse a string in memory, please help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should write inner loop that goes to the half of the string and swap the characters?
The one from i places from the beginning with the one for i places from the end?
The end NUL is left as is.
If the number of characters is odd the middle one is left as is.
If you divide the string length by 2 (shift right one bit) you'll get the number of characters to loop through.
Reminder is either 0 or 1 (in which vase the excess one id the middle character of the string of odd number of characters).
So you swap str[i] and str[last-i] (via a temporary store), where 'last' is the string length - 1.
Often in assembly it's easier to loop backwards: start with len/2 and decrement until the index is zero (ending condition as well for conditional jump to loop beginning).